# Why $\Omega(E) \propto E^N$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

In statistical mechanics class , it is assumed $\Omega(E) \propto E^N$ where $\Omega(E)$ is the number of microstates corresponding to energy $E$ in a system where number of particles is constant and total energy of reservoir and system is constant. The system is in contact with a reservoir and $N$ is the total number of particles in the system. Why is it assumed like that?

Comment: Please give a reference...

Comment: *Which* system do you have in mind?

Comment: @Physiker No, changing the units of energy must change the value of the constant of proportionality so that $\Omega(E)$ (which is a pure number) is unchanged.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Voting to reopen. This is a perfectly clear question.

Comment: It's...  not?  It generally depends on the system and in particular the number of degrees of freedom for each particle.  For example, for a monatomic ideal gas we have $\Omega(E) \propto E^{3N/2}$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Can you please give a reference how $ \Omega(E) $  $\propto $ $E^_(3N/2) $ relation is valid for ideal gas?

Comment: Schroeder, *An Introduction to Thermal Physics*, Section 2.5.  I think it's also in Reif's *Fundamentals of Statistical and Thermal Physics* somewhere but I don't have my copy in front of me and I can't figure it out from the table of contents.